# Pronunciation of ‘d’ in ‘play’d’

Tags: pronunciation

I have to recite *Darkness*, the poem by Lord Byron. But I do not know how to pronounce the *'d* that appears in past tense words like *play'd*. Is it a short sharp *D*, is it soft and trails off, or is it pronounced as its own syllable?

Comment: How would that compare with "plaid"?

Comment: @KalleMP I have always pronounced "plaid" to rhyme with "Dad."

Comment: @MissMonicaE  My ignorance is unbounded, I see now you are on the side of officialdom and I have presumed much all these many years.  Also thank you for pointing out my error in such a gentle way, that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 38):

In Byron's day poetry still permitted the archaic pronunciation of the *-ed* suffix on verbs and participles whose base form ended in an open syllable as a distinct unstressed syllable when this suited the meter.

Spelling the *-ed* suffix as *’d* indicated that the ending was not to be pronounced this way, but as it is in ordinary speech: a consonant closing the open syllable.

In your example, *play’d* is to be pronounced /pleɪd/, as a monosyllable; Byron excludes the alternative pronunciation with a second syllable /pleɪ.ᵻd/

Answer (score 26):

When Lord Byron wrote, some of the past tense *-ed* endings that we pronounce as /d/ were pronounced as /ɪd/. So you should pronounce *play'd* exactly the same way as people pronounce it today, to rhyme with *shade*. (This was probably in fact the way everybody pronounced *played* then, in fact. Shakespeare, two centuries earlier, pronounced *played* with one syllable. Byron was probably being overly careful.)

But if you want to use the same pronunciation as Lord Byron intended, you should probably pronounce *clenched* with two syllables in the line

> Their chins upon their clenched hands, and smil'd.

Shakespeare seems to have consistently pronounced past tenses ending with *-nched* with two syllables. I don't know if this pronunciation was archaic when Byron wrote.

Comment: Just to note the alternate orthography found in other editions: [Their chins upon their clenchéd hands, and smiled](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YNX2PxpS6GcC&pg=PT886&lpg=PT886&dq="Their+chins+upon+their+clenchéd+hands,+and+smiled")

Answer (score 4):

You read the words as if they were spelled without the elision but you omit the sound that is elided.

So in the example you have provided *play'd* you would pronounce the 'd' as in the d at the end of *housed*, *played*, *regained* etc...

As explained on ([thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/elision-phonetics-term-1690638))

> "Elision of sounds can . . . be seen clearly in contracted forms like
>   ... they'd (they had, they should, or they would), haven't (have not) and so on. We see from these examples that vowels or/and consonants can be elided."

Perhaps the easiest way to understand how to pronounce these words is to actually listen to them being pronounced.

Here is the poem being [read aloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6clFZPBCjo) by Nick Gisburne

I've listed the first three time indexes for words with elision that end in *'d*:

> extinguish'd - 00:18
>
> chill'd - 00:47
>
> consum'd - 01:06

Answer (score -3):

It's english so no one agrees or actually knows how to pronounce words. This poem also seems to be using english that isn't modern so it's very likely that people can't actually pronounce some of the words in it correctly.

With that in mind 'd looks like a modern ed. I would pronounce it deh. As a native speaker I'm pretty sure that the D in this case should not say its name.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnO8O00KvYg

Pronounce the "'d" like that.

I don't think anyone actually cares how you pronounce the words that end in ed in this poem, but if you want to be more correct I think you would pronounce them as Edd. The thing is that is an archaic pronunciation - that's not what it sounds like in modern English anymore.

I doubt very strongly that anyone in you recite this to will actually know the correct way to pronounce everything in this poem. For this reason, I recommend you try to figure out the rhyme scheme and pronounce the words so that the rhyme scheme works out. That's probably what people are going to look at when deciding if it was done correctly.

tl:dr; make sure it rhymes.